# Estou com um erro em Javascript e não consigo arrumar

Tags: jquery

Código:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var products = "";
    var url = "https://cdn.rawgit.com/LucasRuy/1d4a5d45e2ea204d712d0b324af28bab/raw/342e0e9277be486102543c7f50ef5fcf193234b6/potions.json";  

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            if(response.erro) {
                $("h2").html(response.erro);
            }else {
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    products += "<ul class='ranking'>";                   
                    products += "<li class='list'><img class='image' src=" + response.data[i].image + "></li>";
                    products += "<li class='list'><p class='name'>" + response.data[i].name + "</p></li>";                    
                    products += "<li class='list'><p class='price'>" + response.data[i].price + "</p></li>";
                    products += "</ul>";               
                }

                $('.box-products').html(products);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Erro:

> script.js:12 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lenght' of undefined

Comment: Dado que o único uso de `length` é em `response.data.length`, pela mensagem de erro, o atributo `data` não existe em `response`. Deveria existir?

Comment: Aparentemente, seu [response.data] não existe. Seria interessante voce colocar uma validação antes do for

Answer (score 2):

O retorno do Ajax não é um array, é uma lista de objetos enumerados dentro do objeto `potions`, e não `data`:

```
{
  "potions": {
    "1": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Aging Potion",
      "image": "aging-potion.png",
      "price": 29.99,
      "effect": "Causes the drinker to advance in age",
      "ingredients": [
        "Red Wine",
        "Prune Juice",
        "Hairy Fungus",
        "Tortoise Shell",
        "Caterpillar",
        "Bat Tongue"
      ]
    },
    "2": {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Bulgeye Potion",
      "image": "bulgeye-potion.png",
      "price": 19.99,
      "effect": "It affects one's eyes, causing them to swell",
      "ingredients": [
        "Beetle eyes",
        "Eel eyes"
      ]
    },
...
```

Com isso você não consegue pegar o `.length` direto. Você pode iterar nessa lista de objetos de duas formas:

**Usando `for` convencional:**

Como a lista de objetos começa do `1`, o valor de `i` no `for` deve começar do `1`, e a condicional usar `<=` (menor ou igual) ao número de objetos, que você consegue pegar usando `Object.keys(response.potions).length`:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= Object.keys(response.potions).length; i++) {
  products += "<ul class='ranking'>";                   
  products += "<li class='list'><img class='image' src=" + response.potions[i].image + "></li>";
  products += "<li class='list'><p class='name'>" + response.potions[i].name + "</p></li>";                    
  products += "<li class='list'><p class='price'>" + response.potions[i].price + "</p></li>";
  products += "</ul>";               
}
```

**Usando `for...in` (melhor):**

Usando `for...in` você consegue iterar os objetos. Este método é melhor porque não fica preso ao nome sequencial dos objetos usado no `for` convencional:

```
for(var i in response.potions) {
  products += "<ul class='ranking'>";                   
  products += "<li class='list'><img class='image' src=" + response.potions[i].image + "></li>";
  products += "<li class='list'><p class='name'>" + response.potions[i].name + "</p></li>";                    
  products += "<li class='list'><p class='price'>" + response.potions[i].price + "</p></li>";
  products += "</ul>";               
}
```

O `i` retorna o nome de cada objeto na lista, independentemente se é uma sequência ou não.